# Android calculator app installs and opens but when clicked on button component, App closes automatically

Tags: android, mobile-application, calculation

I have made an basic deposit amount calculating application, where user can enter amount and tenure in months then he clicks on calculate button then app should show intrest value to the user. If i build this project at android studio using below said code. Application installs and opens on device but when it is clicked on button, Application will closes automatically. I am not understanding whether fault is in below code or device.

```
EditText et1,et2;
TextView mv,ie;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    mv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mv);
    ie=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ie);
}

public void Cumlative(View v){

    float depositamt = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
    float tenure = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

    float matval = (float)((depositamt*tenure)/100);

    ie.setText((int) matval);

}
```

Below is xml file

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Deposit Amount"
    android:id="@+id/et1"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Tenure in Months"
    android:id="@+id/et2"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cumlative"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#8BC34A"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Maturity value"
    android:id="@+id/mv"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Intrest earned"
    android:id="@+id/ie"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/cal"
    android:onClick="Cumlative"/>
```

log:

```
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: Returning from transfer command 0x24;3028 
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: <--_fpc_tac_transfer_data returns tlTci->rsp.cmd_ret;3040 
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: Enter _fpc_tac_load_database_id;2325 
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: _fpc_tac_load_database_id, random_id_size, 96;2349 
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: -->_fpc_tac_transfer_data command 0x29;2866 
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: -->_fpc_tac_send_cmd command 0x02,0x29;2677
```

Comment: Please provide logs from logcat.

Comment: 11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: Returning from transfer command 0x24;3028
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: <--_fpc_tac_transfer_data returns tlTci->rsp.cmd_ret;3040
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: Enter _fpc_tac_load_database_id;2325
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: _fpc_tac_load_database_id, random_id_size, 96;2349
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: -->_fpc_tac_transfer_data command 0x29;2866
11-15 20:59:08.102 15074-15074/? I/fpc_tac: -->_fpc_tac_send_cmd command 0x02,0x29;2677

Comment: Is the above xml and java code are fine ? which part of logs from logcat should i provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please provide the error that shows in your logcat for us to easily identify your error.
Second of all, the error is on this two lines:

```
float depositamt = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
float tenure = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
```

Change them to

```
float depositamt = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
float tenure = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I have changed the code as above but no use and log cat error is as below.

Comment: logcat error is:- 11-15 21:43:43.842 18486-18486/? E/fpc_tac: fpc_tac_init Failed to send init command, 10
11-15 21:43:43.842 18486-18486/? E/fpc_hal: tac init() failed error!! return 10, retry 1

Comment: @GAnilReddy fixed some errors and edited the answer again please take a look

Comment: i have seeing no changes